# Satzzeichen am Ende von Einträgen auf Stichpunktlisten, die ganze Sätze enthalten?

Tags: punctuation, list

Ich habe eine Praktikumsstellenausschreibung geschrieben, die die zugehörigen Anforderungen als ganze Sätze formuliert, diese dann aber in Form einer Liste strukturiert, welche man normalerweise für Stichpunkte verwendet. Ich möchte damit erreichen, dass pro Anstrich eine neue Anforderung bzw. Tätigkeitsfacette in den Mittelpunkt tritt, aber trotzdem ein sprachlich „erwachsener“ Text herauskommt. Modifiziertes Beispiel:

> - In ruhigen Minuten gehst Du uns beim Schreiben von Tests und Dokumentationen zur Hand.
> - In unruhigen Minuten hältst Du uns hingegen durch Mitarbeit im Leitstand den Rücken frei.
> - …
> - Mit X, Y und Z hast Du idealerweise schon erste Erfahrungen gesammelt.

Jeder Anstrich ist ein echter Satz, hat deshalb einen Satzpunkt am Ende. Die Kollegin, die die Textvorgabe in das entsprechend CD-Template eingepflegt hat, hat die Satzpunkte wieder herausgenommen.

Ihre Begründung: Eine Stichpunktanstrichliste würde per Definition nur Stichpunkte enthalten, welche per Definition keine Sätze seien und deshalb per Definition keinen Satzpunkt verdienen würden.

Also ist meine Frage an die hier versammelte Kompetenz:

**Stichpunktanstrich mit vollwertigem Satz – Satzpunkt ja oder nein?** Und warum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Rechtschreibregeln sind hier scheinbar eindeutig:

> § 68: Nach freistehenden Zeilen setzt man keinen Punkt.

Allerdings werden nur die folgenden Beispiele genannt:

> - Überschriften und Werktitel
> - Titel von Gesetzen, Verträgen, Deklarationen und dergleichen sowie Bezeichnungen für Veranstaltungen
> - Anschriften und Datumszeilen sowie Grußformeln und Unterschriften etwa in Briefen

Nichts davon trifft auf deinen Fall direkt zu. Deswegen weitersuchen. Für die relevanteste Fundstelle halte ich § 71 E2:

> E2: Das Komma (und gegebenenfalls der Schlusspunkt) **kann** in kolumnenartigen Aufzählungen fehlen, zum Beispiel:
>
> > Unser Sonderangebot:
> >
> > - Äpfel
> > - Birnen
> > - Orangen

(Hervorhebung von mir)

Da stehen wir nun, wir armen Tore, und sind so klug, als wie zuvor. Da ich die Juristerei leider nicht studiert habe (und schon gar nicht mit heißem Bemühen), muss ich hoffen, dass meine folgende Argumentation stichhaltig ist.

- § 68 trifft meines Erachtens auf den Sachverhalt nicht zu. Es handelt sich nicht um freistehende Zeilen, sondern aufeinanderfolgende Sätze im Sinne einer Aufzählung, die man auch als Fließtext formulieren können hätte – ganz anders als eine typische Überschrift.
- § 71 (2) fordert ein Komma im Falle von Aufzählungen gleichrangiger Wörter und Wortgruppen. § 71 E2 *erlaubt* das Weglassen eines solchen Kommas im Falle von »kolumnenartigen Aufzählungen«, vulgo Spiegelstrichen.
- § 67 fordert den Punkt am Schluss von Ganzsätzen; § 71 E2 *erlaubt* das Weglassen des Schlusspunkts am Ende von durch Kommas trennbaren Spiegelstrichen, wenn dabei gleichzeitig der Satz zu Ende ist.
- Nirgends sonst wird eine Sonderregel für Spiegelstrichaufzählungen gegeben.

Daraus schließe ich folgendes:

- Wenn es sich um ganze Sätze handelt, darf und soll man sie mit einem Schlusspunkt abschließen.
- In Spiegelstrichlisten *darf* der Schlusspunkt nicht entfallen, wenn die Liste nicht durch Kommas getrennt ist.
- Nur dadurch, dass ein Satz hinter einem Spiegelstrich steht, macht ihn das *nicht* zum Stichpunkt – deswegen habe ich den Begriff »Stichpunktliste« oder vergleichbare vermieden.

Folglich halte ich die Meinung der Kollegin nicht für durch die Regeln gedeckt und plädiere für das Setzen von Schlusspunkten an den Satzenden.

---

Eine andere mögliche Argumentation, im Lichte meiner obigen Ausführungen wäre folgende: *De facto* sind deine »Spiegelstriche« nichts anderes als Ein-Satz-Absätze, die noch einmal zusätzlich hervorgehoben werden. Sätze, die Bestandteil von Fließtexten sind, werden auch dann mit einem Punkt abgeschlossen, wenn sie keinen seitenbreitenbedingten Zeilenumbruch enthalten, und alleine einen Absatz füllen. Diese Sorte Satz fällt *nicht* unter die Gültigkeit des § 68, der für freistehende Zeilen die Abwesenheit von Schlusspunkten verlangt.

---

Nebenbei erwähnt: Aus § 71 E2 ergibt sich, dass eine Aufzählung auch folgendermaßen aussehen kann:

> - der erste Punkt,
> - der zweite Punkt, und
> - der letzte Punkt.

Comment: Ich plädiere für Punkt am Ende jedes Satzes, weil solange keine Regel es für diesen Anwendungsfall ausdrücklich untersagt, so gilt nur die eine Regel, die besagt, dass Sätze mit Punkt abzuschließen sind. — +1 btw

Answer (score 6):

Regeln dienen dazu, gewonnene Erkenntnisse zu kodifizieren. Die Erkenntnisse, um die es sich in Sprache und Schrift meistens handelt, sind, wie der Inhalt am leichtesten erfasst und gelesen werden kann.

Solange hinter jedem Stichpunkt nur ein Satz steht, und alle Sätze mit diesem Stichpunkt enden, ist der Punkt am Satzende wohl entbehrlich.

Bestehen einzelne Stichpunkte aber aus mehreren Sätzen, so sollte aus Gründen der Einheitlichkeit auch im letzten Satz ein Punkt gesetzt werden. Mehr noch, wenn manche Sätze nicht am Stichpunkt enden.

Ebenso können Frage- oder Ausrufezeichen am Satzende nötig sein. Auch dann würde die Einheitlichkeitsüberlegung einen Satzpunkt nahelegen.

Ein Punkt am Satzende hilft die richtige Betonung zu finden. Man muss nicht vorschauen um sicher zu gehen, dass hier der Satz endet. Wenn der Punkt beim Lesen hilft, setz ihn.

Ich denke das ist hier der Fall.

Answer (score 5):

Ein Satz wird durch einen Punkt beendet. Y punto.

In der Schule habe ich gelernt, die Kuller, die solche Aufzählungen typographisch auszeichnen, bei der Zeichensetzung zu behandeln, als wären sie nicht da.

Comment: Wunderschöne Ergänzung; Futter für meine Argumentation, die du da nachlieferst! =)

Comment: Solche Übervereinfachungen sind typisch für den Schulunterricht. Man kann Listenpunkte in Sätze einbauen und sollte dann die Spiegelstriche und Zeilenumbrüche für die Zeichensetzung ignorieren, aber heutzutage gibt es viele Listen, die nicht in einem klassischen Satzkontext stehen und daher auch anderen Interpunktionsregeln folgen.

Answer (score 4):

Listen und Aufzählungen werden auf verschiedene Arten in Texte eingebunden und der Inhalt von Listenpunkten kann wortartig, phrasenartig, satzartig oder textartig sein. Die in der Frage zitierte Argumentation mit „per Definition“ trifft jeweils nur auf einen Teilbereich zu und kann daher keine allgemein zuverlässige Aussage treffen, insbesondere gilt sie im vorgestellten Fall nicht.

> ### Zutaten
>
> - 4 Eier
> - 500 g Mehl
> - 500 ml Milch
>
> `↑ wortartige Listeneinträge, koordiniert`
>
> ### Zubereitung
>
> 1. Eier verquirlen`[`,`]`
> 2. mit Mehl verrühren`[`,`]`
> 3. Milch langsam hinzugeben`[`.`]`
> 4. Teig in eine gefettete Form geben`[`.`]`
>
> `↑ phrasenartige Listeneinträge, sequentiell koordiniert`
>
> 30 min bei 200 °C (180 °C Umluft)
>
> ---
>
> Dieses Rezept ist`[`: `/` …`]`
>
> - supereinfach`[`,`]`
> - lecker`[`,`]`
> - bekömmlich `[`und`]`
> - kalorienarm`[`.`]`
>
> `↑ wortartige Listeneinträge, mgl. Satzkontext`
>
> ### Kommentare
>
> - „Echt total einfach!“ – Kochschürze24
> - „Das schmeckt sogar meinem Mann ;)“ – DieKati
> - „Ist das Rezept auch glutenfrei ???“ – VegaNordLover
>
> `↑ satzartige Listeneinträge, unabhängig`

In den markierten Fällen kann man geteilter Meinung darüber sein, ob Satzzeichen am Ende des Listenpunkts bzw. nach der Listeneinleitung verwendet werden sollten, weil es sich um wohlgeformte Sätze handelt. (Nach dem Infinitivimperativ steht übrigens üblicherweise kein Ausrufezeichen.)

Ich empfehle, sich für Listenpunkte nach der Zeichensetzung in Überschriften zu orientieren. Dort entfällt der Punkt immer, auch nach validen Sätzen mit finitem Vollverb; Ausrufe- und Fragezeichen können hingegen stehen, vgl. auch die Zeichensetzungsregeln zur wörtlichen Rede in Anführungszeichen. In Listenpunkten ist allerdings Kleinschreibung am Anfang möglich, in Überschriften eher nicht. Für Text in Tabellen gelten analoge Überlegungen.

Bei ganzen Sätzen, vor allem, wenn entweder auch – absatzartig – mehr als einer pro Listenpunkt stehen kann oder jeder Spiegelstrich einen Satz einleitet, würde ich immer normale Interpunktion verwenden.

Comment: Schönes Beispiel! Klingt wie Eierkuchen, bis zu dem Moment, wo es nicht in eine Pfanne kommt :-) Ist das als Beispiel frei kreiert, oder adaptiert?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Das ist eine völlig beliebige Zusammenstellung mit einigen Grundzutaten. Für Pfannkuchen hätte ich die Eier natürlich getrennt und Eischnee aufgeschlagen.