# Dativ in einer Liste

Tags: dative, list

Was ist richtig:

> Sie werden von folgenden Tieren begrüßt:
>
> - netten Einhörnern
> - lieben Narwalen
> - tollen Nashörnern

oder

> Sie werden von folgenden Tieren begrüßt:
>
> - nette Einhörner
> - liebe Narwale
> - tolle Nashörner

(Es ist klar, dass ohne die Liste Dativ angebracht wäre.) Aber ist es auch mit der Liste der Fall?

**Edit:** Nochmal zur Verdeutlichung meines Problems.

Hier ist die Antwort für mich eindeutig, da wir eine Kongruenz brauchen:

> Sie werden begrüßt von:
>
> - netten Einhörnern
> - lieben Narwalen
> - tollen Nashörnern

Man könnte das auch schreiben als

> Sie werden begrüßt von netten Einhörnern, lieben Narwalen und tollen Nashörnern.

Eine Kongruenz haben wir aber auch hier:

> Sie werden von **folgenden Tieren begrüßt:**
>
> - nette Einhörner
> - liebe Narwale
> - tolle Nashörner

Meine Aussage oben ("Es ist klar, dass ohne die Liste Dativ angebracht wäre.") war wahrscheinlich falsch: Man kann das nicht einfach so ohne die Liste schreiben (Danke an David Vogt in den Kommentaren). Die Frage ist also vermutlich: Was ist hier der Status der Listenpunkte? Was ist die Liste grammatikalisch? Welche Regeln gelten für sie?

**2. Edit:** Es geht mir tatsächlich um die grammatikalische Korrektheit. Der Abschnitt (bzw. ein weniger tierisches Äquivalent) war Teil eines längeren Textes.

Comment: Natürlich ist die Kongruenz auch in Auflistungen zwingend. Welchen Grund sollte es geben, sie sinnentstellend zu ignorieren?

Comment: Was genau heißt *ohne die Liste*?

Comment: @tofro Daß der Doppepunkt und die Aufzählung den Skopus der Rektion beenden, wäre nun nicht **so** weit hergeholt. Im Gesetzblatt steht schließlich auch "Der Bundestag möge beschließen: 1. Die Verordnung vom 1.12.2004 wird mit sofortiger Wirkung..." und nicht "1. daß die Verordnung vom...".

Comment: @KilianFoth Dein Beispiel ist ein ganzer Satz mit einem Doppelpunkt drin (auch in der Aufzählung). Den kan man auch "flach" hinschreiben, ohne Grammatikregeln zu verletzen. Die Kongruenz ist darin gewährleistet. Niemand sagt, dass man einen Nebensatz aus den Listenpunkten machen muss. Von daher: Das ist ein anderes Beispiel, das mit der Frage nichts zu tun hat

Comment: @DavidVogt Danke für die Frage, sie hat mir geholfen, das Problem besser zu beschreiben!

Comment: @tofro Ich habe meine Frage jetzt nochmal (hoffentlich besser) erklärt. Wenn man eine Liste **nicht** flach hinschrieben kann, ohne Grammatikregeln zu verletzen, dann gelten für Listen offensichtlich andere Grammatikregeln als für flache Sätze. Aber welche genau?

Comment: Zitat: „[...] dann gelten für Listen offensichtlich andere Grammatikregeln als für flache Sätze.“ Das ist nicht richtig! Und was das letzte Zusatzbeispiel in Ihrer Frage betrifft: auch dort müssten die aufgezählten Dinge im Dativ stehen.

Comment: Der allgemeine Sprachgebrauch weicht oft von den Regeln ab, teils unfreiwillig, so kennt man Schilder, die brav im Dativ beginnen und später in den Nominativ abgleiten oder , von Mehrzahl wird in Einzahl gewechselt. Reine Gebrauchs-"Texte" mit grammatikalischer Strenge zu bewerten, ignoriert praktische Erfordernisse und das Kosten/Nutzen-Verhältnis: niemand liest sie durch oder vor, stattdessen schaut man auf die Überschrift ("Wie bieten:") und scannt dann bis zum gewünschten Punkt ("Kaffee"). Genauso könnte es bei einem Zoobesuch sein: die Kinder kommen nur mit, wenn es auch Elefanten gibt.

Comment: @P_S kannst du bitte deiner Frage noch Angaben bezüglich des Kontextes hinzufügen. Ist die zitierte Aufzählung teil eines Textes, eine Seite einer Powerpoint-Präsentation, ein Tafelbild, ein Werbeschild, Werbung in einer Zeitung?

Comment: @Wolf, Verzeihung? Zu monieren, dass wir hier Texte „mit grammatikalischer Strenge [...] bewerten“ und obendrein zu suggerieren, „praktische Erfordernisse und das Kosten/Nutzen-Verhältnis“ wären wichtiger, finde ich vor allem (aber nicht nur) auf German StackExchange völlig fehl am Platze. Dass Regeln im Werbebereich häufig gebrochen werden, ist unstrittig. Aber das heißt nicht, dass wir das deswegen gutheißen sollten. Abgesehen davon ist die Frage allgemeiner; Aufzählungen kommen nicht nur auf Werbeschildern vor.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich hoffe, wir erfahren noch etwas mehr über den Kontext, in dem sich die Frage gestellt hat. Ich moniere nicht die grammatikalische strenge Bewertung, sondern bezweifle, dass man es tatsächlich mit Text zu tun hat. Grammatik (meine private Auffassung) erfüllt die Aufgabe, die Struktur eindimensionaler Symbolfolgen ableitbar zu machen. (In der akustischen Übertragung haben wir Satzmelodie und Rhythmus, im direkten Kontakt zusätzlich Mimik und Körpersprache.) Wenn wir Schriftzeichen in der Fläche anordnen, erhalten wir Ausdrucksmittel dazu, die die Grammatik "entlasten" können.

Comment: Das Verlassen von Regeln hat üblicherweise einen Sinn (und mag dann vieleicht auch durch diesen Sinn gerechtfertigt sein): In der Werbung ist es z.B. "auffallen", in Hinweisschildern u.U. Kürze und Übersichtlichkeit. Die Kongruenzregeln der deutschen Grammatik in typographischen Aufzählungen zu verlassen, hat keinen für mich einleuchtenden Sinn. Wenn mir einer einen nennt, ändere ich vielleicht meine Meinung

Comment: @Wolf Es geht mir tatsächlich um die grammatikalische Korrektheit. Der Abschnitt (bzw. ein weniger tierisches Äquivalent) war Teil eines längeren Textes.

Comment: @P_S danke für die Info. Ich denke, in diesem Fall wäre es besser gewesen, ein Beispiel zu wählen, das näher am Text bleibt, vielleicht einen größeren Ausschnitt zu wählen. Ich denke, der Rahmen spielt eine große Rolle, auch für die Anwendbarkeit von Regeln, siehe z.B. die "kolumnenartigen Aufzählungen", bei denen das Komma fehlen *kann*.

Answer (score 2):

Die äußere Form der Darstellung ändert für gewöhnlich nichts an der Grammatik. Ob also eine Aufzählung hintereinander in einer Reihe

> Sie werden von folgenden Tieren begrüßt:
> netten Einhörnern, lieben Narwalen, tollen Nashörnern.

untereinander in einer Liste

> Sie werden von folgenden Tieren begrüßt:
>
> - netten Einhörnern,
> - lieben Narwalen,
> - tollen Nashörnern.

treppenartig eingerückt

> Sie werden von folgenden Tieren begrüßt:
>
>         netten Einhörnern,
>
>     lieben Narwalen,
>
> tollen Nashörnern.

gespiegelt

> .nrenröhsaN nellot ,nelawraN ,nrenröhniE :tßürgeb nereiT nedneglof nedrew eiS

oder sonst wie dargestellt wird, die Kasuskongruenz (in diesem Beispiel Dativ) bleibt bestehen.

Da Sie es in den Kommentaren angesprochen haben, möchte ich noch auf den Doppelpunkt, oder vielmehr die Zeichensetzung allgemein, eingehen.

Ob vor der Aufzählung ein Doppelpunkt steht oder nicht, spielt keine Rolle. In jedem der Beispiele könnte man sämtliche Satzzeichen weglassen, und trotzdem wäre *Dativ* der einzig korrekte Kasus für die aufgezählten Dinge.

Satzzeichen dienen dazu, die syntaktische, grammatische Struktur zu *kennzeichnen*. Die Struktur ist aber auch ohne Satzzeichen da. Zum Beispiel bleibt ein Nebensatz auch dann ein Nebensatz, wenn ich vergesse, ihn mit einem Komma vom Hauptsatz abzugrenzen. Genauso bleibt der Kasus fest, egal ob ich einen Doppelpunkt vor die Aufzählung setze oder nicht.

Comment: Hast du eine Quelle für *gespiegelt*? (just kidding)

Comment: Der Argumentation kann ich nicht folgen. In meinem Beispiel gibt es auch in Fall 2 eine Kasuskongruenz: *Sie werden **von folgenden Tieren begrüßt**...*. Danach gibt es einen Doppelpunkt, der für mich nicht zur "Darstellung" gehört, sondern zur Grammatik.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Sehe ich erstmal anders.

*Wie der Verlauf der frühneuhochdeutschen Zeit bereits erkennen lässt, entwickelt sich die Funktion der Zeichensetzung von einer rhythmisch-intonatorischen hin zu einer syntaktischen. Somit ist auch die heutige Interpunktion vorwiegend dazu da, in einem Text logisch-syntaktische Grenzen zu setzen (z.B. Sätze und Teilsätze zu kennzeichnen) die einer grammatischen Regelung unterliegen.* (https://www.uni-bielefeld.de/lili/personen/useelbach/STUD/Beschorner/interpunktion.htm)

Alternativ natürlich https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunktion

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Habe mich evtl. unklar ausgedrückt. Natürlich zeigt die Interpunktion an, was schon da ist. In diesem Fall zeigt sie für mich eben an, dass in meinem Beispiel eine grammatische Struktur vorhanden ist, die es in deinem Beispiel nicht gibt, weswegen man mein Beispiel mMn auch nicht ohne weiteres hintereinander in einer Reihe schreiben kann (und selbst bei der Spiegelung bin ich mir nicht sicher).

Comment: Die Antwort (im Kern korrekt) gleitet so sehr ins Verspielte ab, dass sie an Wert verliert. Ganz ehrlich: ich fand das nicht mal beim ersten Lesen amüsant.

Comment: @Wolf, die ursprüngliche Frage war (grob gesagt), ob sich der Kasus ändert, wenn aus einer Reihenaufzählung eine Punktliste wird. Und meine Antwort sagt nur: Nein,  der Kasus hängt nicht von der äußeren Form ab. Und ich untermauere das mit zwei weiteren Beispiele für äußere Formen, weil mir ein einzelnes Beispiel nicht genügt. Daran sehe ich nichts *Verspieltes*, und ich habe mit der Antwort auch nicht *amüsieren* wollen, auch wenn Mitglied amadeusamadeus das Beispiel mit der Spiegelung offenbar lustig fand.

Comment: Aber die Spiegelung ist doch wirklich abwegig. Wenn ich mir Beschriftungen in GUIs ansehe, finde ich kaum Grammatik. Die Schilder, auf denen wir die groben Schnitzer belächeln, betrachte ich als Vorläufer grafischer Benutzeroberflächen. Ich würde nicht sagen, dass alles erlaubt ist, aber es gibt eine Übergangszone/Grauzone in der Praxis, die man schlecht ignorieren kann.

Comment: @P_S, ich habe das Beispiel jetzt angeglichen und die Diskussion über den Doppelpunkt in der Antwort aufgegriffen.

Answer (score 1):

Wie [Björn Friedrich bereits ausgeführt hat](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/63336/5437), ist es im Beispiel regelkonform, die gesamte Aufzählung in die Dativform zu bringen.

Andererseits verringert die Flexion den Wiedererkennungswert der im Zentrum der Aussage stehenden Objekte von [Gebrauchstexten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebrauchstext); auch leiden einfache Nutz- und Wartbarkeit:

- innerhalb digitaler Medien kann *Copy&Paste* helfen, Tippfehler zu vermeiden
- auf Werbe- und Angebotstafeln ändert man einzelne Einträge gelegentlich

Um also die *Usability* solcher Listen zu erhöhen, wird manchmal die Grammatik selbst gebeugt, und es entstehen die in der Frage aufgeführten Varianten. Aber es gibt Alternativen.

Sobald man *von* durch *durch* ersetzt, was die Liste in den Akkusativ zwingt, fallen die lästigen Endungen weg

> Sie werden begrüßt durch:
>
> - nette Einhörner
> - liebe Narwale
> - tolle Nashörner

eine weitere Lösung wäre

> Es begrüßen Sie:
>
> - nette Einhörner
> - liebe Narwale
> - tolle Nashörner

Das Komma und das *und* in [*kolumnenartigen Aufzählungen*](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26437/5437) kann man weglassen.

Answer (score 1):

In solchen typographischen Auflistungen sind **Zeichensatzregeln** (teilweise(*)) außer Kraft gesetzt und durch die typographische Darstellung ersetzt, u.U. sogar verdeutlicht.

**Grammatikregeln**, die den Sinnzusammenhang zwischen den Worten regeln, müssen allerdings weiter gelten - ansonsten kann, allein durch den Wunsch nach einer "übersichtlichen" Darstellung, der Sinn eines Textes verloren gehen. Zu den wichtigsten Grammatikregeln hierbei gehört die *Kongruenz* in Kasus, Numerus und Genus. Geht diese verloren, entsteht u.U. eine Sinnentstellung.

(*) Allerdings nur dann, wenn die Liste reine, einfache Aufzählungen enthält. Sobald z.B. die Liste eine Auflistung von Nebensätzen darstellt, wird dringend empfohlen, die einzelnen Listenpunkte der Aufzählung nach üblichen Rechtschreibregeln durch Kommata abzugrenzen und mit einem Punkt zu beenden.

Answer (score 1):

Meines Erachtens ist im Problembeispiel der Kasus der aufgezählten Elemente nicht grammatisch festgelegt.

> Sie werden von folgenden Tieren begrüßt: nette(n) Einhörner(n), liebe(n) Narwale(n), …

Selbstverständlich regiert die Präposition *von* den Dativ; aber mit *begrüßt* ist der Satz vollständig und abgeschlossen, und über eine Satzgrenze hinaus kann die Präposition keinen Kasus regieren. ([Rektion](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/1017), nicht [Kongruenz](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/577), ist der revelante Begriff: Die Präposition fordert vom abhängigen Element einen bestimmten Kasus, ohne selbst ein Kasusmerkmal zu haben.)

Was passiert, wenn der Kasus wie im Problembeispiel nicht grammatisch festgelegt sind? Es kommt zu Unsicherheit und Schwankungen. Ich denke, man wird sowohl Beispiele mit parallelem Kasus (in diesem Fall Dativ) als auch mit dem "unregierten Kasus", also Nominativ, finden.

Interessanter finde ich aber Beispiele wie das folgende:

> Den Sieg machten folgende Teilnehmer unter sich aus: Erster wurde X, auf Platz zwei landete Y und Z wurde Dritter. *(Variation eines Korpusbelegs)*

Hier folgt auf eine Ankündigung von Teilnehmern  eine Aufzählung von Sätzen. Das bedeutet: Die Elemente dieser Art von Aufzählung können nicht nur im Kasus, sondern sogar in der Form vom ankündigenden Element abweichen.

Zwei mit dem Problembeispiel kontrastierende Beispiele seien genannt: Fälle mit gespaltenen Konjunkten oder abgetrennten Appositionen.

> Er wurde damals **von seiner Frau** begleitet **und seinem Bruder**.
>
> Sie werden freundlich **vom größten Landsäugetier** begrüßt, **einer Giraffe**.

Die nachgestellten Elemente sind eindeutig Teil des Satzes und der Präposition untergeordnet. Daher ist nur der Dativ (als der von der Präposition regierte Kasus) möglich. In beiden Fällen kann man, im Gegensatz zum Problembeispiel, umstellen und so zeigen, daß alle Elemente Teil desselben Satzes sind.

> Von seiner Frau und seinem Bruder wurde er damals begleitet.
>
> Vom größten Landsäugetier, einer Giraffe, werden Sie freundlich begrüßt.

Comment: Die Annahme, dass "Präpositionen nicht über Satzgrenzen wirken" läßt sich mit vielen Beispielen widerlegen.

Comment: @tofro Dann schreib doch bitte eins dazu. Wie soll mir der Kommentar sonst helfen?

Comment: Nimm z.B. einfach eine Frage/Antwort-Folge: Dann ist klar, dass die Präposition in der Frage natürlich über die Satzgrenze hinaus auch in der Antwort relevant ist.

Comment: @tofro Eine in der Frage auftauchende Präposition würde doch in der Antwort wiederholt? *Mit welchem Mitarbeiter haben Sie denn gesprochen? - Ich glaube, mit dem Chef.* Aber die Antwort ist sowieso frei, genauso gut ginge auch *das war der Chef* oder *das weiß ich nicht mehr*.

Comment: Danke @DavidVogt, das erklärt vermutlich meine (intuitiven) Zweifel. Aber ist der Satz "Sie werden von folgenden Tieren begrüßt" wirklich vollständig? Spielt da die Semantik von "folgenden" nicht in die Grammatik rein?

Comment: @P_S Ich sehe das parallel zu Sätzen wie *ich möchte ihnen jetzt drei Gründe nennen*: syntaktisch und semantisch vollständig, aber auf der Ebene des Textes auf etwas Nachfolgendes verweisend (Textdeixis).

Answer (score 0):

Richtig:

> Sie werden von folgenden Tieren begrüßt:
>
> - netten Einhörnern
> - lieben Narwalen
> - tollen Nashörnern

Comment: Danke für die Antwort - kannst du sie vielleicht begründen?